# Same event handler for two events which requires different signature

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, textchanged, validating-event

I have a method that I want to invoke both on the `TextChanged` and `Validating` events. The problem is that the `e` parameter of `TextChanged` is of type `EventArgs` while the `e` parameter of `Validating` is of type `CancelEventArgs`.

I could obviously do something like this:

```
void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => Method();
void TextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) => Method();
```

but I wonder if there is an option to make both events to have the same event handler.

Comment: Just use `void MyHandlerName(object sender, EventArgs e)` - it is valid for both events.

Comment: But why would you want to do that? I would have different handlers and then call common code from both of them.

Comment: @Evk - Thanks. I have tried but in the "Events" tab of the "Properties" panel, I don't see the method.

Comment: Well don't know anything about that panel, but I'm quite sure handler with this signature is valid for both events (because CancelEventArgs inherit from EventArgs), try to do that in code for example (`textBox.Validating += MyHandler`)

Comment: @CodingYoshi - the specific reason is that the method I want to invoke validates the `TextBox`, and I want it to be validated both when the user types and when it loses its focus.

Comment: @Evk it seems to work. But mister_giga wrote it as an answer so I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: @sipo so take the code and place it in a common method. Call it from both handlers.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - that is the hassle I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since EventArgs is base for CancelEventArgs, you can use (object sender, EventArgs e) for both events. On properties window you may not see proper event name because you use base class so you can write name there manually